# Here maps request autocomplete suggestions formatted labels for localized address formatting

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

In Key Concepts of Geocoder Autocomplete API i read "formatted labels for localized address formatting (for example, house no. first or street name first) and structured address fields in customizable order".

But how can i do it?
For example:

```
    { "suggestions": [
  {
   "label": "Italia, Roma, 00187, Roma, Via Sicilia",
...
```

**in the label field I would like the street first!**

Comment: Are you looking to altering the response of the geocoder API ? please confirm

Comment: Yes, right! Altering the response of the geocoder API. I would like to "label": "Via Sicilia, Roma, 00187, Roma, Italia",

Comment: Is there anyway to do this @HEREDeveloperSupport

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of parameters which you can pass to autocomplete geocoding API request to get street first.

> matchLevel=street

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=Berli&apiKey=&matchLevel=street
```

and **formatted labels for localized address formatting** this is the part of response structure which may be you have seen here.
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/resource-type-response-suggest.html

Comment: No, this not seems to work. 
ENDPOINT: https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com
PARAMS: &matchLevel=street&maxresults=5&query=via+nazionale+1+roma
RESPONSE:
{"suggestions":[{"label":"Italia, Roma, Roma, Via Nazionale, 2","language":"it","countryCode":"ITA","locationId":"NT_4-bIFRhIwRGf7r4L.7ThbA_yA","address":{"country":"Italia","sta